# Where can I find a Pharo+Seaside3+Magritte image for experimenting with the "An Introduction to Seaside" book?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak, seaside

Where can I find a Pharo image to run the code from this book:
http://www.swa.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/seaside/tutorial

Scoured the mailing lists for a Pharo alternative and they were supposed to be http://www.lukas-renggli.ch/job/Magritte%202/, then moved http://source.lukas-renggli.ch/ but I'm unable to pin it down.

The printed version (using the old Seaside 2.8.4) referenced Squeak images that were supposed to be available here: 
http://www.seaside.st/download/squeak#167943699

As far as I can tell moved somewhere else? Found Squeak images that work http://ftp.squeak.org/various_images/seaside/Squeak4.1/ but can't tell if they are the right ones.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this one: https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/job/PharoWeb/PHARO=50,VERSION=stable,VM=vm/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/PharoWeb.zip

Use this image with the pharo 5.0 vm. You can get it from the pharo site.

This is part of a Pharo MOOC: http://files.pharo.org/mooc/. I highly recommend taking this MOOC. It helped me a lot.

Comment: Mention links in comments' section

Comment: Good answer! Also add where you got the VM to go with the image you posted.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial was written with Squeak in mind and should work for Seaside 3.

You can install Seaside in a Squeak image with the installation instructions from the Squeak Website (http://squeak.org/projects/#seaside).

The latest pre-built Squeak image with Seaside (Squeak 4.4 with Seaside 3.0.8) can be found on Squeak's file server at http://ftp.squeak.org/4.4/seaside/.

At the time of writing, a more current image based on Squeak 5 and Seaside 3.2 is being prepared.

**[EDIT]**

Execute the following in Squeak 4.5, 4.6, or 5.0 to get a current Metacello (taken from https://github.com/dalehenrich/metacello-work):

```
"Get the Metacello configuration (for Squeak users)"
Installer gemsource
    project: 'metacello';
    addPackage: 'ConfigurationOfMetacello';
    install.

"Bootstrap Metacello Preview, using mcz files (#'previewBootstrap' symbolic version"
((Smalltalk at: #ConfigurationOfMetacello) project 
  version: #'previewBootstrap') load.

"Load the Preview version of Metacello from GitHub"
(Smalltalk at: #Metacello) new
  configuration: 'MetacelloPreview';
  version: #stable;
  repository: 'github://dalehenrich/metacello-work:configuration';
  load.

"Now load latest version of Metacello"
(Smalltalk at: #Metacello) new
  baseline: 'Metacello';
  repository: 'github://dalehenrich/metacello-work:master/repository';
  get.
(Smalltalk at: #Metacello) new
  baseline: 'Metacello';
  repository: 'github://dalehenrich/metacello-work:master/repository';
  load.
```

Then, the following will install Seaside+Magritte

```
Metacello new
    configuration: 'Seaside3';
    repository: 'http://www.smalltalkhub.com/mc/Seaside/MetacelloConfigurations/main';
    version: #stable;
    load: 'OneClick'.

Metacello new
    configuration: 'Magritte3';
    repository: 'http://www.smalltalkhub.com/mc/Magritte/Magritte3/main';
    version: #stable;
    load: 'Magritte-Seaside'.
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. The image in the link doesn't contain Magritte. It has configuration for Magritte3 inside, but the code provided in the book doesn't run without issues. Trying to install Magritte3 wants Zinc which isn't in the image...etc

Comment: When it wants Zinc, something is not configured right there, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

In Pharo 4 & 5, use the last part of Tobias' answer to first load Seaside and then Magritte. Pharo has Metacello loaded by default.

After loading, open the Seaside Control Panel to add an adapter (ZnZincServerAdaptor), and start that.

On the [pharo contributions ci](http://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution) there are several builds that already have Magritte & Seaside loaded (like QCMagritte)